# Add Analysis Services to a clustered SQL Server 2008 instance

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssas, cluster-computing, database-cluster

I have an existing multi-instance SQL 2008 cluster, and I'm trying to add Analysis Services to an existing instance. I start the installation, pick "Add features", configure SSAS, and then on the final pre-installation check, I fail the "Existing clustered or cluster-prepared instance" check. Of course I'd fail this check - I'm trying to add a feature to an existing clustered instance. Here's a picture of the error:

[image: "Existing clustered or cluster-prepared instance" error message]
<sub>(source: [trycatchfinally.net](http://trycatchfinally.net/UploadedImages/SQL%20-%20Existing%20Clustered%20Instance.gif))</sub>

Has anybody successfully added a feature to a clustered instance in SQL 2008? I can't believe it can't be done - my alternative is to remove SQL from one node, try to add the feature again, hoping I don't fail this same check (though I probably will), and then re-add to the second node. This seems dangerous and unnecessary.

I found another person who had the same question, but the people answering it clearly aren't even reading the question, since they're mentioning how to cluster a server, and that he should use SQL 2000, so this is no help at all (though I'd love to point him here once it's answered: http://forums.techarena.in/software-development/1209984.htm

Comment: Can I get some comments for the close votes? Is this a duplicate? Is it poorly worded? Anybody?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the SQL Server 2008 Failover Clustering whitepaper.

http://download.microsoft.com/download/6/9/D/69D1FEA7-5B42-437A-B3BA-A4AD13E34EF6/SQLServer2008FailoverCluster.docx

Page 31 & 32

"Note: SQL Server 2008 does not support adding features to an existing failover cluster instance, so Analysis Services cannot be added to an existing instance of SQL Server. To share a resource group with an instance of SQL Server, you must choose to install Analysis Services during the initial installation of SQL Server."

Comment: This gives me a sad face, but I suppose it's the official answer. I'm not sure how I missed that in the whitepaper, but thanks for the link.

Answer (score 0):

Warning: I have never added analysis services to my existing cluster environment.

But this is how i would go about it:
1. Remove one node from cluster ( provided u have > 2 nodes ).
2. Install Analysis services.
3. Bring the node back into cluster.

Comment: That's what I'm thinking I have to do. I'm afraid I'll still get the error, since the remaining node will still be "cluster-ready", but I'll try this in the morning and post back here.

Comment: Sorry - this didn't work. I still get the error, I assume since the instance is still "cluster-prepared", as the installer puts it. This is driving me nuts! Thanks for the attempt, though.

Answer (score 0):

The option to add or remove features is not supported either when running the setup through SQL Server Installation Center or when running the setup from a command prompt. For more information on the what happens when you try to add a feature through setup you can refer to the following forum post:

```
Why do I get ‘Rule “Existing clustered or clustered-prepared instance” failed’ error while adding new features to an existing instance of SQL Server Failover Cluster?
```

This article can be found [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlforum/2011/04/19/forum-faq-why-do-i-get-rule-existing-clustered-or-clustered-prepared-instance-failed-error-while-adding-new-features-to-an-existing-instance-of-sql-server-failover-cluster/).

If you need to add or remove features to an existing installation you need to reinstall the virtual instance with the required features. For additional information you can refer to the following topics in SQL Server Books Online:

```
How to: Remove a SQL Server Failover Cluster Instance (Setup)
How to: Create a New SQL Server Failover Cluster (Setup)
```

Note: The SQL Server Analysis Services resource is a part of any SQL Server failover cluster’s resource group where Analysis Services is installed. Although it is possible to install both Database Engine and Analysis Services in the same resource group, it is generally recommended to install them as separate instances. Analysis Services is not dependent on SQL Server, and it should be installed to a separate resource group for maximum availability and performance.

Answer (score 0):

Try to find necessary /skiprules parameter.

I have used the following setup SQL command to install SSRS feature with clustered instance:

> Setup.exe
>   /SkipRules=StandaloneInstall_HasClusteredOrPreparedInstanceCheck
>   /Action=Install